# how to make fillable forms with reportlab in python

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

can anyone please help me with creating forms in python using the reportlab lib.
i am totally new to this and i would appreciate sample code
thanks

Answer (score 7):

Apparently reportlab does not support creating fillable pdf forms. The only thing I found about it being present in the API dates from 2003, afterwards all statements clearly say no.

I'm answering this so late because this is one of the highest hits when you enter 'reportlab forms' in google. I do agree with Travis you should google easy questions yourself, but this isn't really clearly answered anywhere.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case any more: https://www.reportlab.com/documentation/relnotes/34/